# Editing the color of the selected date Material Calendar View

Tags: java, android, calendar, calendarview

I have several dates in the database.

I would like to put these dates in my calendar. with changed background. depending on other variables.

for now a stiff code

```
   private void  colorCalendar(){
       String dt = "12122018";
           Date date = new Date(dt);
           SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
           String formatted = sdf.format(date);
       //calendarView.setSelectionColor();

       calendarView.setSelectedDate(LocalDate.parse(formatted));
   }
```

But errors.

I use https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview
android studio.

but I can change it

I'm counting on your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Material Calendar View**

> Good code is its own best documentation

The library here has good documentation regarding to your use-case I think,
When you say depending on other variables, I'd like to suggest going through this link or provide some more information regarding it.
[Customization](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/wiki/Customization#custom-labels)